# Can the tags x and x11 be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

- [x](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/x) has 42 questions
- [x11](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/x11) has 60 questions

Interestingly, just today someone added a tag wiki for [x11](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/x11); my personal thought would have been that [x](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/x) should be used despite it having fewer questions.

Comment: Seems sensible that X should be the tag - one day there may be an X12

Comment: @voretaq7, perhaps [xserver] would have been better?  Though [xserver] is pretty close to [xserve]. I wonder if most of what is in [xorg], and [xserver] should be migrated over to the main tag, since that was what was chosen.

Comment: @Zoredache I would go with [x-window-system] or [x-windows] personally

Comment: Somebody merged [tag:x] to [tag:x11] already. If it was you, please write an answer so I can put the nice green check mark next to it.

Answer (score 3):

Is X11 (or the possible future X12) the only valid case for X? It seems to me that any single letter tag is far from descriptive and in fact the X tab probably shouldn't even exist for that very reason. e.g. X is just as much part of OS X as it is of X11. I haven't checked its usage on existing questions but I also don't believe past usage is necessarily a good indicator of future usage.

Comment: The questions tagged [tag:x] which refer to [tag:macosx] seem to be in the minority, from a quick look.

Comment: That was just one example that popped into my head. It's just that I see X11 as being the more valid case that just X, because it's much more obvious what it's referring to.

Comment: 8 of 42 questions tagged [tag:x] actually referred to [tag:macosx]. They have all been dealt with. None of the 42 had anything to do with X11 on Mac OS X.

Comment: Maybe you've just presented your own case for not merging the two tags.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: "None of the 42 had anything to do with X11" sounds to me like a good argument for *not* merging X and X11.

Comment: None of the 42 had anything to do with X11 on Mac OS X.